# Frame of Reference chosen in Hafele-Keating experiment

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, reference-frames, time-dilation

I do not understand why we chose the frame of reference which is at rest with respect to Earth's center. I get that it does not experience the acceleration due to centripetal force of Earth's rotation around its own axis. But it still experiences the acceleration doe to centripetal force on Earth while revolving around the Sun, right? So do we ignore that here? Or is there some other explanation for this?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment):

> The [Hafele–Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment) was a test of the theory of relativity. In October 1971, Joseph C. Hafele, a physicist, and Richard E. Keating, an astronomer, took four cesium-beam atomic clocks aboard commercial airliners. They flew twice around the world, first eastward, then westward, and compared the clocks against others that remained at the United States Naval Observatory. When reunited, the three sets of clocks were found to disagree with one another, and their differences were consistent with the predictions of special and general relativity.